# How to handle situations in which the DOM changes overwriting some variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rendering

I am using Ruby on Rails, jQuery v1.8.3 and jQuery UI v1.9.2. In a view file I am rendering a partial template this way:

```
<%= render :partial => 'template_name', :locals => { :div_id => 'div_id1' } %>
```

The related `template_name` file contains the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var item = $('#<%= div_id %>')

  alert(item.selector) // Display #div_id1
</script>
```

On the same page, through an AJAX request, I retrieve and add to the DOM the same partial template but with `:locals => { :div_id => 'div_id2' }`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var item = $('#<%= div_id %>')

  alert(item.selector) // Display #div_id2
</script>
```

Making the above, *after* the AJAX request, I "lose" the reference to the `#div_id1` since `item` becomes related to `#div_id2`.

How should I handle that situation in order to avoid "overwriting" variables? How can I "isolate" (maybe, namespacing or using some jQuery features) those variable?

Comment: real problem is: you're using global variables

Comment: I would avoid trying to mix client-side JavaScript with server-side output.

Comment: @apneadiving - How should I make those variables to be local?

Comment: you should scope whatever you're doing, it's really the base of every solid js architecture.

Comment: @Explosion Pills - How should avoid mixing client-side JavaScript with server-side output in my case?

Comment: @apneadiving - How should I scope the `item` variable in my case? Is there some "recipe" / "technique" to make that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code snippets are self-contained, you should be able to just move the code into a private scope.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        var item = $('#<%= div_id %>');
        alert(item.selector); // Display #div_id2
    })();
</script>
```

*Though i disagree with having server-side code generating javascript-based ui widgets.*

Comment: **You**: Though i disagree with having server-side code generating javascript-based ui widgets. **I**: What are alternatives to avoid that?

Comment: Post more about your code / view, and explain what you are trying to do. We can help you to refactor I guess

Comment: @user12882 That depends very much on your application structure. For all we know you may be coded into a corner where this is your only option.

Comment: @MrYoshiji - As I explained in the question, in the same page I am trying to AJAX-render multiple times the same partial template but I have problems that seem related to scoping JavaScript variables included in those templates.